# "Warning: You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work."

Tags: linux, sass, gruntjs

When I try to grunt:serve, I get this warning.

```
Warning: Running "sass:server" (sass) task
Warning: 
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
Use --force to continue.
```

So I tried `which ruby` and `which sass`. ruby was found in /usr/bin/ruby but sass was not found in any of my path folders. I used ls in /usr/bin and saw a sass item in red which I believe means it is an archived or compressed file. I also found a sass folder in /usr/bin/node_modules so I deleted the sass archive and copied the sass folder in node_modules to my /usr/bin folder. I am still getting this warning and css never compiles. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Remove the `/usr/bin/sass` folder. Sass is not a Node module. Then you can try `gem install sass`.

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't installed Sass on your machine and you are using it in some way. If you already have Ruby installed on your machine, install Sass by running following command:

```
gem install sass
```

and your problem will go away.